# What is ipconntrac? Do I need it?

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, iptables

To give you some background

I have recently bought a Linode server and I have configured ubuntu 10.10 64 bit on it. The server will start getting around 500 req/second and will be constantly under load. The main purpose of the server would be to ask as a nginx reverse proxy.

Now my question is: What all changes to the server (apart from nginx config which I guess I am quite confident about now), should I make to my ubuntu box to make sure its performance is optimum in my situation. My Keep-Alive in nginx is 0 and the server is supposed to have min latency and maximum uptime.

I dont plan to do anything on it other than nginx. One of the concerns which I had in the past was ipconntrack. I dont know much about ipconntrack and iptables and why do I need them and what will happen if I disable them / enable them and how to best disable them. I have also seen that many times my queue of TIME_WAIT connections increases.

What are the other parameters I should consider optimizing for my server

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TIME_WAIT is a TCP state indicating that the connection is closing. It is normal for a large number of connections to be in this state on a busy server.  A closed connection will stay in this state for about 4 minutes before disappearing.  ipconntrac has nothing to do with this.

ipconntrac is part of the stateful firewall available with Linux.  Basically, it tracks the state of a connection so that it does not have to check each packet.   Once a connection is accepted, it is tracked and can be given an express acceptance with the a check for an Established state.  Some protocols use multiple ports and with the appropriate helper modules Related connections can get the same express ride.

Some distributions load the firewall as modules.  On these distributions ipconntrac can be disabled by unloading the module and any related modules.  To prevent it loading on restart there is a module blacklisting mechanism.

Unless you have a firewall in front of your server I would install a firewall script disabling access from the internet on ports other than 80 and 443 (if HTTPS is supported).  I use Shorewall which has some good example scripts.  In your case, the two interface example would be a good starting point.